# Loop for cleaning NAs in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to write this code more effectively?

```
for (k in 1:ncol(tr)){
  temp=tr[[k]]
  temp[is.na(temp)] = mean(temp[!is.na(temp)])
  tr[[k]]=temp
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace a for loop for matrices or dataframes, `apply`is often a good idea:

```
apply(tr, 1,  function(temp) {temp[is.na(temp)] <- mean(temp, na.rm=TRUE); temp})
```

More information about `apply`-like functions [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html).

Comment: should be `mean(temp, na.rm=T)`

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(tr, function(x) { 
  x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  return(x) 
})
```